# I am looking to scrape the name and URLs of all videos in a Vimeo channel. Is this possible?

Tags: screen-scraping, vimeo

I am building a website where video sermons are located on a Vimeo channel ... hundreds of them.  I would like to scrape the videos in this channel an get from the the title of the video and the URL.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes it is, do you have a particular programming language in mind? in python will be easy..

Comment: Never worked with Python .. but am open to whatever will work.

Comment: Give [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) a try, it's buit for scraping web pages like it's name sais, but if you want a more specific answer post more details

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Vimeo API instead of scraping for content. Scraping may result in getting banned from Vimeo, especially if you want metadata on hundreds of videos.

More information about the Vimeo API can be found on the developer site below, but as another user mentioned you should provide more information about what your intent is, what you've tried, and the programming languages you're comfortable using.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start